# What needs to be installed to query access database with powershell

Tags: powershell, microsoft-access

I want to query a Microsoft Access (2007) database with Powershell, but I don't know exactly what to install on a new host.

Here is the beginning of a list:

- Microsoft Office (at least MS Access)
- Microsoft Access Database Engine 2010 Redistributable

In addition, let's say we have a 64 bits Windows host and a MS Office 32 bits. How to make it work ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There are plenty of existing answers to this question. It is typical to have an x86 and x64 version of Powershell installed on a host machine.

Comment: Hi root, well, actually, I have something that works on a computer using the open method of an instance of `New-Object -ComObject ADODB.Connection`. This does not work on another one. The main difference between both of them is that the first one is a full 32 bits system while the one which does not work is a 64 OS and MS office seems to be 32 bits...

Comment: Try running your Powershell script from the 32bit version of the Powershell/Powershell ISE (C:\Windows\SysWOW64\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\).

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you have all you need. With PowerShell you have access to ADO.NET with its full list of providers, including one for Access databases.

Have a look at [this article](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/threekings/2008/07/18/ado-net-in-powershell-update-sql-data-examplesample/) about working with databases from PowerShell using ADO.NET

For completeness look up Access ADO.NET connection strings.

Put the two together and you've got what you need.